# Android get all countries on array spinner

Tags: android, android-spinner

I've searched a lot but the stuff I found was a little confused.

I need to get the android country list and set default the user locale.

For example:
I'm registering an user account and I need to insert the country, in that spinner will show all countries but by default will appear my default locale.

Right now I have:

```
private Spinner spCountry;
private String array_spinner[];
```

...

```
spCountry = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spCountry);

array_spinner = new String[1];
array_spinner[0] = "Portugal";

ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, array_spinner);
spCountry.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Thank you all for the help!

Answer (score 34, accepted):

As for me, i iterate the available Locales and add each of the item into an arrayList. And of course i have to ignore duplicates, and empty strings. Here is my code:

```
 SortedSet<String> countries = new TreeSet<>();
 for (Locale locale : Locale.getAvailableLocales()) {
     if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(locale.getDisplayCountry())) {
          countries.add(locale.getDisplayCountry());
         }
        }

Spinner citizenship = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.input_citizenship);
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, getCountryListByLocale().toArray(new String[0]));
citizenship.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: You can also use a Set in stead of a List, so you only have to check on empty strings because a Set can't contain duplicate items.

Answer (score 8):

You can use

```
private static final String DEFAULT_LOCAL = "Portugal";
```

Then use it to set default selection as follows.

```
ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, array_spinner);
spCountry.setAdapter(adapter);
spCountry.setSelection(adapter.getPosition(DEFAULT_LOCAL));
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

**UPDATE:**
Create `arrays.xml` in `res/values`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string-array name="country_arrays">
        <item>Malaysia</item>
        <item>United States</item>
        <item>Indonesia</item>
        <item>France</item>
        <item>Italy</item>
        <item>Singapore</item>
        <item>New Zealand</item>
        <item>India</item>
        <item>Portugal</item>
    </string-array>

</resources>
```

Then use following in your `activity` to get all the countries.

```
array_spinner = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.country_arrays);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer but my main issue is: How I get all countries from android to my spinner?

Comment: see my updated answer,if it works for you then mark it as answer.

Comment: It's possible to use locale to pull all countries and display on array right? Hardcoded it's bad (xml)

Comment: @FilipeOS, This is just an example, so that you can understand how things work.

Comment: Yes that I understand, I just can't figure it out how to push locale countries (all) and display them on the spinner. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

A helpful and customizable Country Picker for your needs.

Gradle

```
repositories {
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}

compile 'com.github.ekimual:country-picker-x:1.0.0'
```

Sample Usage:

```
/* Declare */
CountryPickerDialog countryPicker;

/* Name of your Custom JSON list */
int resourceId = getResources().getIdentifier("country_avail", "raw", getApplicationContext().getPackageName());

countryPicker = new CountryPickerDialog(MainActivity.this, new  CountryPickerCallbacks() {
      @Override
      public void onCountrySelected(Country country, int flagResId) {
            /* Get Country Name: country.getCountryName(context); */
            /* Call countryPicker.dismiss(); to prevent memory leaks */
      }

      /* Set to false if you want to disable Dial Code in the results and true if you want to show it 
         Set to zero if you don't have a custom JSON list of countries in your raw file otherwise use 
         resourceId for your customly available countries */
  }, false, 0);

countryPicker.show();
```

Reference https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/4390

Answer (score 0):

Why not doing it like this? Just getting the countries in a list, sorting it and inserting it.

```
String[] locales = Locale.getISOCountries();
List<String> countries = new ArrayList<>();
countries.add("**Select Country**");

for (String countryCode : locales) {

        Locale obj = new Locale("", countryCode);

        countries.add(obj.getDisplayCountry());

}
Collections.sort(countries);
countrySpinner.setItems(countries);
```